# grep a number from the line and append it to a file

Tags: awk, grep, cat

I went through several grep examples, but don't see how to do the following.

Say, i have a file with a line

```
! some test here and number -123.2345 text
```

i can get this line using

```
grep ! input.txt
```

but how do i get the number (possibly positive or negative) from this line and append it to the end of another file? Is it possible to apply grep to grep results? 
If yes, then i could get the number via something like

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,}|\-[0-9]{1,}"
```

p/s/ i am using OS-X

p/p/s/ i'm trying to fetch data from several files and put into a single file for later plotting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The format with your commands would be:

```
grep ! input.txt | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,}|\-[0-9]{1,}" >> output
```

To `grep` from `grep` we use the pipe operator `|` this lets us chain commands together. To append this output to a file we use the redirection operator `>>`.

However there are a couple of problems. You regexp is better written: `grep -Eoe '-?[0-9.]+'` this allows for the decimal and returns the single number instead of two and if you want lines that start with `!` then grep `^!` is better to avoid matches with lines what contain `!` but don't start with it. Better to do:

```
grep '^!' input | grep -Eoe '-?[0-9.]+' >> output
```

Comment: Are you going to allow for the decimal point in the example?  What about `+123.234`?

Comment: thanks for your answer, almost works. But on os-x "-?" seems not be allowed. When i use "[0-9]{1,}|\-[0-9]{1,}" i got two numbers - before and after the "."

Comment: @Denis yes if forgot that if the pattern starts with `-` it would cause problems. The fix is to use `-e`. See edit.

Comment: hm, the result is still two numbers, e.g. "-123" and "2345"

Comment: For your given line `grep '^!' input | grep -Eoe '-?[0-9.]+'` will produce the output `-123.2345`.

Comment: sorry, i missed the dot. Works indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'm/.*?([\d\.\-]+).*/g;print $1' your_file >>anotherfile_to_append
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo="! some test here and number -123.2345 text"
$echo $foo | sed -e 's/[^0-9\.-]//g'
$-123.2345
```

Edit:-

for a file,

```
[ ]$ cat log
! some test here and number -123.2345 text
some blankline
some line without "the character" and with number 345.566
! again a number 34
[ ]$ sed -e '/^[^!]/d' -e 's/[^0-9.-]//g' log > op
[ ]$ cat op
-123.2345
34
```

Now lets see the toothpicks :) `'/^[^!]/d'` `/` start of pattern, `^` not (like multiply  with false), `[^!]` anyline starting with `!` and `d` delete. Second expression, `[^0-9.-]` not matching anything within 0 to 9, and . and -, (everything else) `//` replace with nothing (i.e. delete) and done :)

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` in a character class and this won't be much help unless you show how it's used within the context of the question.